# Avoiding redundant build to make tessaract android library && link tessaract library to c++ NDK

Tags: android, makefile, java-native-interface, tesseract

Now I am making an application using on MacOSx with Tessaract and Android NDK.
I use Eclipse as an IDE to develop the program.

I have two questions to ask:

1). I set up tessaract using the most famous example "tess-two" and modified a bit to fit with my existing code. I copied folder "com_googlecode_leptonica_android" and "com_googlecode_tessaract_android" to /jni folder. Then edit Android.mk for setting path to those library folder. Everything works fine! Except one thing..  Every time that I build the project, I need to build both "leptonica" and "tessaract" library again and again..in order to get libtess and liblept.. It takes soooo long.  How can I edit android makefile (Android.mk) not to build those libraries.. just compile my code only... thats all.. Here is my Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
MY_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)
TESSERACT_PATH := $(call my-dir)/com_googlecode_tesseract_android
LEPTONICA_PATH := $(call my-dir)/com_googlecode_leptonica_android

include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
include /Applications/eclipse-android/OpenCV-2.4.3-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_PATH := $(MY_PATH)
LOCAL_MODULE    := my_project
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := cppmain.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
)
```

2). I found a lot of examples about using tessaract with Android. However most of them using tessaract with Java (call via JNI) and call JNI from java code (Java -> Tessaract C++ JNI -> Tessaract C++). I cannot find any example that call tessaract from c++ NDK (Java -> my JNI -> my C++ -> Tessract C++). The reason that I want to call tessaract directly from c++ is portability.

Answer (score 1):

Use **PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY**, something like

```
LOCAL_PATH = $(MY_PATH)/com_googlecode_tesseract_android/lib
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := tesseract
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libtesseract.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

LOCAL_PATH = $(MY_PATH)/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/lib
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := leptonica
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libleptonica.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

LOCAL_PATH := $(MY_PATH)
LOCAL_MODULE    := my_project
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := cppmain.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -ltesseract -lleptonica

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The tesseract project does not contain prebuilt libraries, but if you follow the official instructions, these libraries will be built. Using PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY only helps you to avoid unnecessary rebuilds of these libraries all the time. Same approach is recommended for libjpeg and libpng, as long as you don't change these libraries yourself.

Comment: What about libjpeg and libpng? Also I can't see any prebuilt files in the tess-two project.

Comment: All right, this did actually work:) Would you mind updating your answer, so I can assign you the bounty?